# Which Association Should I Use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has 5 core models. I'm trying to figure out the best way to associate the models. How many tables should I build and which kind etc?

Here are the associations I would like to include and their respective models:

**User**
Has many boards
Has many lists
Has many cards
Has many comments

**Board**
Has many users
Has many lists
Has many cards

**List**
Belongs to board
Has many cards

**Card**
Belongs to board
Belongs to list
Has many comments

**Comment**
Belongs to card
Belongs to user

Comment: I'm confused, because you ask 'what associations should I use' and then you list out the exact associations you want to use. Use those associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :boards
  has_many :lists, as: listable
  has_many :cards, as: cardable
  has_may :comments, as: commentable
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :lists,  as: listable
  has_many :cards,  as: cardable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :cards, as: cardable
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cardable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :comments, as:commentable
end
```

To establish HABTM relation you have to create a table named 'users_boards'

Comment: This looks awesome dude, thanks. Could I hassle you to explain the correct schema.rb also? Does a list need a board ID column? Does a card need a list ID column etc?

Comment: for 'Comment' model, you have to add column 'commentable_id'. Please do the same for all polymorphic tables.

Answer (score 0):

As Board and User are having many to many relationship, there will be a new table for it, if you want HABTM you can use it.

User(id, name, other_attributes...)

Board(id, name,...)

List(id, name, user_id(fk),...)

Card(id, name, user_id(fk), list_id(fk), board_id(fk),...)

Comment(id, comment_msg, user_id(fk), card_id(fk),...)

Board_User(board_id(fk), user_if(fk))  --- M-M relation

Few attributes might change if there is a has_many through relation.

FK-- Foreign key, you can use has_many through depending on your requirements.

Comment: What does "(fk)" stand for? Should I use a has_many through relationship as you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Using polymorphic associations has some limitations, so please do through it then decide to use a polymorphic association

http://codeblow.com/questions/pros-and-cons-for-ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-associations/